# Unzip Archive with Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, zip, unzip

is there a built-in support in Groovy to handle Zip files (the groovy way)?

Or do i have to use Java's java.util.zip.ZipFile to process Zip files in Groovy ?

Comment: Is this still a valid question/answer? What Groovy version is this referring too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't a native way. But check out the article [Powerful Groovy](https://web.archive.org/web/20151120062929/http://blog.xebia.com/2008/05/25/powerful-groovy/) on how you'd add a `.zip(...)` method to File, which would be very close to what you're looking for. You'd just need to make an `.unzip(...)` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, that article disappeared from the blog. Luckily [there is an archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20151120062929/http://blog.xebia.com/2008/05/25/powerful-groovy/). But the [More Groovy Power](http://blog.xebia.com/more-groovy-power/) article is also good.

Answer (score 54):

Maybe Groovy doesn't have 'native' support for zip files, but it is still pretty trivial to work with them.

I'm working with zip files and the following is some of the logic I'm using:

```
def zipFile = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(new File('some.zip'))

zipFile.entries().each {
   println zipFile.getInputStream(it).text
}
```

You can add additional logic using a `findAll` method:

```
def zipFile = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(new File('some.zip'))

zipFile.entries().findAll { !it.directory }.each {
   println zipFile.getInputStream(it).text
}
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me that groovy's .text replaces all the traditional java stream handling boiler plate.

Answer (score 40):

In my experience, the best way to do this is to use the Antbuilder:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()   // create an antbuilder

ant.unzip(  src:"your-src.zip",
            dest:"your-dest-directory",
            overwrite:"false" )
```

This way you aren't responsible for doing all the complicated stuff - ant takes care of it for you.  Obviously if you need something more granular then this isn't going to work, but for most 'just unzip this file' scenarios this is really effective.

To use antbuilder, just include ant.jar and ant-launcher.jar in your classpath.

Comment: @{Kirk G}. Do you know if following this approach, it is possible to make AntBuider quiet (not outputting to screen)?

Comment: how do you use patterns here? how to unzip selective files?

Comment: Note that ant.unzip is a simple wrapper around the existing ant unzip task.  The parameters you give are simply passed directly.  See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html for more information.

Comment: This approach is massively slow

Answer (score 4):

The Groovy common extension project provides this functionality for Groovy 2.0 and above: https://github.com/timyates/groovy-common-extensions

Answer (score 4):

The below groovy methods will unzip into specific folder (C:\folder). Hope this helps.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.zip.ZipFile

def unzipFile(File file) {
    cleanupFolder()
    def zipFile = new ZipFile(file)
    zipFile.entries().each { it ->
        def path = Paths.get('c:\\folder\\' + it.name)
        if(it.directory){
            Files.createDirectories(path)
        }
        else {
            def parentDir = path.getParent()
            if (!Files.exists(parentDir)) {
                Files.createDirectories(parentDir)
            }
            Files.copy(zipFile.getInputStream(it), path)
        }
    }
}

private cleanupFolder() {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File('c:\\folder\\'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This article expands on the AntBuilder example.

http://preferisco.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-goovy-antbuilder-to-zip-unzip.html

However, as a matter of principal - is there a way to find out all of the properties, closures, maps etc that can be used when researching a new facet in groovy/java?
There seem to be loads of really useful things, but how to unlock their hidden treasures? The NetBeans/Eclipse code-complete features now seem hopelessly limited in the new language richness that we have here.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip using AntBuilder is good way.
Second option is use an third party library - I recommend [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/)

Answer (score 0):

Although taking the question a bit into another direction, I started off using Groovy for a DSL that I was building, but ended up using Gradle as a starting point to better handle a lot of the file-based tasks that I wanted to do (eg., unzip and untar files, execute other programs, etc). Gradle builds on what groovy can do, and can be extended further via plugins.

```
// build.gradle
task doUnTar << {
    copy {
        // tarTree uses file ext to guess compression, or may be specific
        from tarTree(resources.gzip('foo.tar.gz'))
        into getBuildDir()
    }
}

task doUnZip << {
    copy {
        from zipTree('bar.zip')
        into getBuildDir()
    }
}
```

Then, for example (this extracts the `bar.zip` and `foo.tgz` into the directory `build`):

```
$ gradle doUnZip
$ gradle doUnTar
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def zip(String s){
    def targetStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(targetStream)
    zipStream.write(s.getBytes())
    zipStream.close()
    def zipped = targetStream.toByteArray()
    targetStream.close()
    return zipped.encodeBase64()
}
```